# How does one use the IPrintable interface?

Tags: c#, list, interface

I'm having some problems with IPrintable interface.

I have class Student class that inherits from the Person class + studentID and class Person (name, lastname). And i have to write a IPrintable with Print() procedure. Print() should print out every field from Person or Student class. Next i have to create 4 objects.

1. Class object Person assigned to variable of type Person
2. Class object Student assigned to variable of type Person
3. Class object Student assigned to variable of type Student
4. Class object Student **assigned to variable of type IPrintable**

Next i have to create list of IPrintable objects and add to this list all created objects and print this objects in loop using Print() method.

Can someone help me with code or show me an article about this interface?

// EDIT

Thanks. I'm still confused about two things. This is my code:

Person.cs

```
class Person : IPrintable
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;

    public Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }


}
```

Student.cs

```
class Student : Person
{
    public int ID;

    public Student(string FirstName, string LastName, int ID) : base(FirstName, LastName)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + " [" + this.ID + "]";
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person o = new Student("John", "Smith", 231312); 
        Console.Write(o.ToString());

        return;
    }
}
```

I have also IPrintable.cs

```
interface IPrintable
{
    void Print();
}
```

Where should I put Print() function to access it from Person and Student class? I don't know how to make an  "Class object Student assigned to variable of type IPrintable".

I think that it will be something like:

```
IPrintable x = new Student("x", "x", 2231);
```

But how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPrintable` is not an interface that's included in C#; you're supposed to make it yourself. It will look like this:

```
public interface IPrintable {
    void Print();
}
```

So you should read up on interfaces in general, the consequences of having a class implement an interface, and *polymorphism* (assigning an object reference to a variable of a more general type).

Answer to your edit: As the compiler has probably told you, `Person` must contain a `public void Print()` method since that class implements `IPrintable`. `Student` doesn't have to have one since it inherits the one from `Person`, but if you want a `Student` to be printed differently, you'll need to *override* the method there, with `public override void Print()`.

Indeed, your last code snippet is what they're asking for. What about it seems to not be working?

Also: please do read up on the topics I mentioned. Don't just be satisfied by the compiler accepting `IPrintable x = new Student("x", "x", 2231);`, but work on understanding what is actually happening (that single line does three different things: instantiating a new `Student` object, creating a new `IPrintable` variable, and then assigning the object to the variable), why it is legal to do this, what the difference is to doing e.g. `Person x = new Student("x", "x", 2231);`, and why it is not legal to do `Student x = new Person("x", "x");`. There is solid logic behind all the rules that are involved here, but a lot of teachers sadly gloss over that and focus on just the syntax (and push too much syntax onto the students at the same time...)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me a lot.

"but a lot of teachers sadly gloss over that and focus on just the syntax (and push too much syntax onto the students at the same time...)"

You're right